# How can i fix python ModuleNotFoundError into exe?

Tags: python-3.x

im trying to compile a python code, from py to exe, basically when i run i get a module error,ModuleNotFoundError no module named 'cryptography'
how can fix this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: install the missing module (`pip install cryptography`) and build your exe again